# avoid adding xmlns attribute in xml response when applying XSLT

Tags: xslt, xml-namespaces

I had a XML document that I needed to change the root node. With what little knowledge I could scrape off the net I was able to get things looking like what I wanted except that the child nodes of my XML had new xmlns attributes in them. The XML that I was applying transformation looks like:

```
<gmd:MD_Metadata xmlns="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" 
  xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" 
  xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" 
  xmlns:gmi="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmi" 
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" 
  xmlns:gmx="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmx" 
  xmlns:gsr="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gsr" 
  xmlns:gss="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gss" 
  xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" 
  xmlns:srv="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/srv" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd 
  http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/metadata/published/xsd/schema/gmd/gmd.xsd">
  <gmd:language>
    <gmd:LanguageCode 
      codeList="http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php" 
      codeListValue="eng" codeSpace="ISO639-2"
      >eng</gmd:LanguageCode>
    </gmd:language>
    ......
</gmd:MD_Metadata>
```

My XSLT looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"
  xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" 
  xmlns:gmi="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmi">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"  indent="yes"/> 

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <gmi:MI_Metadata 
      xmlns="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmi" 
      xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" 
      xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"  
      xmlns:gmi="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmi"  
      xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"  
      xmlns:gmx="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmx"  
      xmlns:gsr="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gsr"  
      xmlns:gss="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gss"  
      xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts"  
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
      xmlns:srv="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/srv"  
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmi  
      http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/metadata/published/xsd/schema.xsd" >
      <xsl:for-each select="/*/node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </gmi:MI_Metadata>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the output looks like:

```
<gmi:MI_Metadata xmlns="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmi"  
      xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco"  
      xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"  
      xmlns:gmi="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmi"  
      xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"  
      xmlns:gmx="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmx"  
      xmlns:gsr="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gsr"  
      xmlns:gss="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gss"  
      xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts"  
      xmlns:srv="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/srv"  
      xmlns:v1="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"  
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmi  
      http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/metadata/published/xsd/schema.xsd">
  <gmd:language xmlns="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd">
    <gmd:LanguageCode  
      codeList="http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php"  
      codeListValue="eng" codeSpace="ISO639-2" 
      >eng</gmd:LanguageCode>
    </gmd:language>
    .......
</gmi:MI_Metadata>
```

I wanted to avoid having **xmlns="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"** in the output in the child nodes, is there any way I can achieve that? I noticed that when I change portion of the xslt to :

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<gmi:MI_Metadata xmlns="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" ....
```

the xmlns vanishes but then the header/root node is not what the client wants in the output! So I was not sure what I could do. Your insight would be highly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of `exclude-result-prefixes`, `xsl:copy-of` will copy namespaces, per the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copy-of):

> The xsl:copy-of element can be used to insert a result tree fragment into the result tree...[w]hen the result is a node-set, all the nodes in the set are copied in document order into the result tree; copying an element node copies the attribute nodes, **namespace nodes** and children of the element node as well as the element node itself...

Therefore, you need do (more) of the copying yourself. For instance, here's one piece of the solution, a rule to copy an element:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="copy" priority="1">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="copy"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Then copy stuff as normal

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="copy">
    <xsl:copy />      
</xsl:template>
```

Then, in your code, you can do

```
<xsl:for-each select="/*/node()|@*">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="." />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Ton of thanks to both torazaburo and @C. M. Sperberg-McQuee for your responses. I applied the xslt fragments that torazaburo provided and was able to get rid of the xmlns attribute in the child nodes. I did see xlink:type="simple" attached to some of the child elements but I think I can google something out to take care of it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to read up on the exclude-result-prefixes attribute.

They have a default namespace declaration for the gmd namespace, of course, because they are copied from input that makes that namespace the default (as well as binding it to the prefix `gmd`).  I'd try changing your xsl:copy-of into something more like the conventional identity transform, so that you can try overriding the default namespace declaration in the child elements.

```
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:for-each
    select="$ns-carrier/namespace::*[local-name() = 'xmlns']">
    <xsl:copy/>
  <xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:for-each select="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:copy>
```

(Not tested, so take this with a grain of salt.)

It may help to remind yourself (and the client!) that unless you are doing something unusual and a little dirty with namespace bindings, then for any reasonably good XML tool chain, this is a purely cosmetic issue and not a substantive one.  (That is, be prepared to tell yourself and your client that it really shouldn't matter, if you can't manage to get the stylesheet to do what you want.  By trying to make namespace management happen automatically, the designers of XSLT have made it very hard to do it manually.)